# Is there a STL way to validate that a (text) file is read-only first?

Tags: c++, stl

Also, is there a cross-platform way to change the attribute of a file from read-only to writeable?

Thanks much,
Bert

Answer (score 7):

Check out [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).  It'll do what you need.  I believe this is <strike>one of the parts of boost that is going to be included in the next version of C++, at which time it will become part of the STL, but right now it's</strike> a (free) 3rd-party library.  It's so common that it can almost be considered standard though.

Comment: Why do you believe it will be part of the next C++ standard? I can't find any reference to it in the draft I have.

Comment: Yeah it is not mentioned in the wikipedia article either. I suspect this is wishful thinking

Comment: from the link in my answer: "A proposal, N1975, to include Boost.Filesystem in Technical Report 2 has been accepted by the C++ Standards Committee."

Comment: Unfortunately, TR2 is not part of C++0x but will come later. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is to use operating system specific features - C++ has no functionality in this area.